# I am getting the error props is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a class which contains a grid of swappable items but I am getting the error props is not defined in the line after render(). I am fairly new to react and I want to be able to implement this class such that I can add a remove and add feature later on.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Swappable from './components/SwappableComponent'
import './App.css';
import DataTable from './components/tableWidget';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";


const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  }
});

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    componentDidUpdate() {

    }

    render() {
      const { classes } = props;

      return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id='1' content={<DataTable/>}/></Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}> <Swappable id='2' content="#2"/></Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id='3' content="#3"/></Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id='4' content="#4"/></Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }

  App.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Comment: `const { classes } = props;` should be `const { classes } = this.props;`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you should use `this.props` instead of just `props`. Change the

```
const { classes } = props;
```

To

```
const { classes } = this.props;
```

**EDIT**

About your comment, you could structure your state like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        papers: [
            {
             id: 1,
             content: <DataTable />
             xs: 12,
             sm: 6,
            },
            {
             id: 2,
             content: "#2",
             xs: 12,
             sm: 6,
            },
            // All the other papers
        ]
    {
}
```

And then, render the grid as below:

```
render() {
      const { classes } = this.state;
      return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
          {this.state.papers.map(paper => (
            <Grid item xs={paper.xs} sm={paper.sm}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id={paper.id} content={paper.content}/></Paper>
            </Grid>
         </Grid>
      </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm. If I wanted to move the grid items into the state so that I can remove and add as needed what do you think the best way to implement that would be?

Comment: @IndushaSembakutti, answered your question in the edit

Answer (score 0):

Props are parameters of a Class, so they should go along with theirs.

```
const {classes} = this.props;
```

I think this should resolve the problem